# How to get total processing time when using wait(NULL) function?

Tags: c, time, wait

I want to know processing time of simple multiprocessing code but if parent process uses `do while(wait(NULL) > 0);` to wait child processes, clock() of parent process doesn't return processing time.

I guess `wait(NULL)` makes `clock()` return only unwaiting time (total time except waiting).

Is there other way to check total processing time?

Comment: Do you want the children's cpu usage times?

Comment: `clock()` returns *CPU time* used, by the process in which it is called.  A process does not consume CPU time while it is blocked, whether on `wait()` or on some other blocking call.

Comment: If so, you need `wait3()` or `wait4()`. If you want total cpu time of all (exited) children, not specific ones, `times()` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tms_cutime` from `clock_t`.

Reference
- [times() — Get process and child process times](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rttims.htm)